# When I use remix,there is a issue "Gas estimation failed,VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode"

Tags: solidity, remix, gas, invalid-opcode

When I use function `setDailyAssessmentInfo`, error is raised:

> Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The
>   transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending? 
>   VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode

Here is my code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

contract DailyAssessmentScoreContract {

   struct dailyAssessment{
        string dailyAssessmentId;
        string[] period;
        uint[] score;
    }
    dailyAssessment[] daily_assessment;


   function stringsEqual(string storage _a, string memory _b) internal returns (bool) {
        bytes storage a = bytes(_a);
        bytes memory b = bytes(_b);
        if (a.length != b.length)
            return false;
        // @todo unroll this loop
        for (uint i = 0; i < a.length; i ++)
            if (a[i] != b[i])
                return false;
        return true;
    }
    function stringToUint(string s) constant returns (uint result) {
        bytes memory b = bytes(s);
        uint i;
        result = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            uint c = uint(b[i]);
            if (c >= 48 && c <= 57) {
                result = result * 10 + (c - 48);
            }
        }
    }

   function setDailyAssessmentInfo(string _dailyAssessmentId, string _period, string _score) public {
       bool write = false;
       uint score = stringToUint(_score);
       for(uint i=0; i<=daily_assessment.length; i++)
       {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
           if(stringsEqual(daily_assessment[i].dailyAssessmentId, _dailyAssessmentId))
           {
               daily_assessment[i].period.push(_period);
               daily_assessment[i].score.push(score);
               write = true;
           }
       }
       if(write==false)
        {
            daily_assessment[i].dailyAssessmentId=_dailyAssessmentId;
            daily_assessment[i].period.push(_period);
            daily_assessment[i].score.push(score);
        }
   }

   function getDailyAssessmentInfo(string _dailyAssessmentId) public constant returns (uint) {
       uint score;
       for(uint i=0;i<=daily_assessment.length;i++)
       {
           if(stringsEqual(daily_assessment[i].dailyAssessmentId, _dailyAssessmentId))
           {
               uint sum = 0;
               uint scoreLength = daily_assessment[i].score.length;
               for(uint j=0;j<=scoreLength;j++)
               {
                    sum = sum + daily_assessment[i].score[j];
               }
                score = sum / scoreLength;
           }
       }

       return (score);
   }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in

```
for(uint i=0; i<=daily_assessment.length; i++)
```

Iterating over array, if it grows too large might cause an out of gas error and since being a variable length array is causing gas estimation error.

You can change your design to use `mapping` instead of array.

`mapping(string => dailyAssessment) daily_assessment;`

Use a `map` in which `key` will be the `daily assessment id` and `value` will be the struct `dailyAssessment`.

```
function setDailyAssessmentInfo(string _dailyAssessmentId, string _period, string _score) public {
   bool write = false;
   uint score = stringToUint(_score);

   dailyAssessment storage assessment = daily_assesment[_dailyAssesmentId];
   if(assesment.dailyAssesmentId == _dailyAssesmentId)
       {
           assessment.period.push(_period);
           assessment.score.push(score);
           write = true;
       }
```

Regarding your comment : "here is another problem that I want to use "getDailyAssessmentInfo" to get the sum of score array,a error raise likes above Gas estimation errored with the following message", the problem is exactly the same. It seems you are calculating average of the scores in this `getDailyAssessmentInfo` function. It involves using a loop over all the score and calculate the average. So, the ideal solution would be calculating average without using any loops.

I suggest you to calculate average when inserting the data (in `setDailyAssessmentInfo`), store it and just fetch that average score using a get function. But, remember that the calculation should not use loop. I have used simple idea in the code below to do so.

```
struct dailyAssessment{
    string dailyAssessmentId;
    string[] period;
    uint[] score;
    uint averageScore;
}

function getDailyAssessmentInfo(string _id) returns (uint){
   return daily_assessment[_id].averageScore;
}

function setDailyAssessmentInfo(string _dailyAssessmentId, string _period, uint _score) public {
   uint average = daily_assessment[_dailyAssessmentId].averageScore;
   uint N = daily_assessment[_dailyAssessmentId].score.length;

   uint newAverage = (average * N + _score) / (N + 1);
   daily_assessment[_dailyAssessmentId].averageScore = newAverage;
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: Thank u,it works.here is another problem that I want to use "getDailyAssessmentInfo" to get the sum of score array,a error raise likes above "Gas estimation errored with the following message"

Comment: function getDailyAssessmentInfo(string _dailyAssessmentId) public returns (uint) {
        uint score;
        uint sum = 0;
        uint scoreLength = daily_assessment[_dailyAssessmentId].score.length;
        for(uint j=0;j<=scoreLength;j++)
        {
            sum = sum + daily_assessment[_dailyAssessmentId].score[j];
        }
        score = sum / scoreLength;
       
       return (score);
   }

Comment: @Kyrie I have updated the answer to reflect your second problem. If that solved your problem then upvote and accept the answer.